# Simple way to delete existing pods from Python

Tags: python, kubernetes, microservices, pytest, chaos

I have end-to-end tests written in pytest, running on a Kubernetes cluster in Namespace `foo`. Now I want to add simple chaos engineering to the tests to check the resilience of my services. For this, I only need to delete specific pods within `foo` -- since K8s restarts the corresponding service, this simulates the service being temporarily unreachable.

What is a simple way to delete a specific pod in the current namespace with Python?

---

What I have tried so far:

Since I did not find a suitable example in https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/tree/master/examples, but the ones using pods looked quite complex,
I looked into `kubetest`, which seems very simple and elegant.

I wanted to use the `kube` fixture and then do something like this:

```
pods = kube.get_pods()
for pod in pods:
  if can_be_temporarily_unreachable(pod):
    kube.delete(pod)
```

I thought calling pytest with parameter `--in-cluster` would tell `kubetest` to use the current cluster setup and not create new K8s resources.
However, `kubetest` wants to create a new namespace for each test case that uses the `kube` fixture, which I do not want.
Is there a way to tell `kubetest` not to create new namespaces but do everything in the current namespace?

Though `kubetest` looks very simple and elegant otherwise, I am happy to use another solution, too.
A simple solution that requires little time and maintenance and does not complicate (reading) the tests would be awesome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use [`delete_namespaced_pod`](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CoreV1Api.md)(from [CoreV1Api](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CoreV1Api.md)) to delete specific pods within a namespace.

Here is an example:

```
from kubernetes import client, config
from kubernetes.client.rest import ApiException
config.load_incluster_config() # or config.load_kube_config()

configuration = client.Configuration()

with client.ApiClient(configuration) as api_client:
    api_instance = client.CoreV1Api(api_client)
    
    namespace = 'kube-system' # str | see @Max Lobur's answer on how to get this
    name = 'kindnet-mpkvf' # str | Pod name, e.g. via api_instance.list_namespaced_pod(namespace)
    
    try:
        api_response = api_instance.delete_namespaced_pod(name, namespace)
        print(api_response)
    except ApiException as e:
        print("Exception when calling CoreV1Api->delete_namespaced_pod: %s\n" % e)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot (+1). How do I find out the namespace that the code itself is running in? I saw https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/issues/363, but `load_kube_config()` uses the in cluster config, right?

Answer (score 5):

A continuation to an existing answer by Tibebes. M

> **How do I find out the namespace that the code itself is running in?**

There's two ways to do this:

1. Use Downward API to pass pod namespace to a pod environment variable:

   - https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/#the-downward-api
   - https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/#capabilities-of-the-downward-api See `metadata.namespace`
2. Use your template engine / helm to additionally pass environment variable namespace to a pod. Example:

   ```
            env:
            - name: CURRENT_NAMESPACE
              value: "{{ .Values.namespace }}"
   ```